# postgres dblink password with spaces

Tags: postgresql

Postgres 9.2 is used. Can't put password with spaces in it.

```
select * from dblink
('...password=$pass$password with spaces$pass$', $Query$ select 1$Query$) as r (i int                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            );
```

> ERROR:  could not establish connection DETAIL:  missing "=" after
>   "with" in connection info string

I'm not new on it - see http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/gh335n$158h$1@news.hub.org

First I thought it was UTF-8 password, but then discovered, that it was unescaped space

Comment: You have a Unicode password with spaces in it? Brave...

Comment: yes, and it works well with .pgpass, in bash, in php and all the rest. Now it almost works in pg_dblink extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
select * from dblink
    ('...password=password\ with\ spaces\', $Query$ select 1$Query$) as r (i int                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            );
```

instead...